# Terminating Unused BX Cable in Place

Tags: junction-box, old-house, cables

I have an unused BX cable with power to it in my former coal cellar of my 1925 house. The main panel has been upgraded and has Romex wire. I planned to cap the ends of the BX in a metal junction box held in place with a clamp with blank cover over it. Would this be ok? Do I cap each wire separately? The box would be on the ceiling joist in the basement. Removal of the wire would be extremely difficult.

*Updated with more info from comments:*

Where is the other end of the bx? –
manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact

It goes up it the ceiling/wall between a joist and the old brick chimney. There’s only about 1.5” between the two where it’s fished through. Then I can’t see it. I’d post a photo, but I’m not sure how to yet. –
Pittsburgh

It has power to it, which surprised me. –
Pittsburgh

Comment: Where is the other end of the bx?

Comment: It goes up it the ceiling/wall between a joist and the old brick chimney. There’s only about 1.5” between the two where it’s fished through. Then I can’t see it. I’d post a photo, but I’m not sure how to yet.

Comment: So I’m not sure.

Comment: It’s hanging down and has some odd plastic looking end, which because of the age probably isn’t plastic. Looks like a connector or plug of some sort. It’s odd.

Comment: So it is not connected to power on either end?

Comment: It is. I checked it before I cut it off thankfully lol.

Comment: If it is disconnected on  both ends and it is not in any boxes that have power then you can do anything you want with it. If one end is in a box that has any power in it the you need to cap each wire.

Comment: I haven’t tried to see which breaker it’s on yet though. Was planning that tomorrow when the wife could help.

Comment: It has power to it, which surprised me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well put a receptacle or light *(never met a former coal cellar that couldn't use another light)* on the box and connect the wires to that, but if not doing so, capping the wires inside a closed junction box, preferably with a note on the cover specifying which fuse or breaker feeds it would be the thing to do if leaving it live.

If the wires have degraded to the point that you don't feel you should use them, then you really should find where this connects to power and disconnect it there, at which point you can merely remove all accessible parts of the cable and abandon the inaccessible parts. Merely being BX is not a good reason to do this, but BX with inner insulation in poor condition you might want to. Don't knee-jerk to that, though.

Comment: The next owner, wanting to add a light, would appreciate at least the hint of how to run new wires in the tight places.

Comment: It’s fished up through the tiniest hole along the chimney. My guess is that it connects to the new wiring somewhere in the wall. The breaker runs the living room wall near the chimney, but I can’t see where. I went to the local hardware and will cap in a metal box and write the info on it you suggested. The wire and cloth seems in good shape so even though there’s Romex feeding another newer light, but I may still tap it later for some additional lighting. I use it for brewing now and plan to put a ceiling in so I could use it then. Thanks for the help and suggestions!